# How to do third level in complex document from three tables in json to mongodb using Pentaho

Tags: mongodb, pentaho-spoon

I have three tables in one database. These tables have a foreign key between them. Table1 is master from Table2, and Table 2 is master from Table3.

I want to get data values and transform in MongoDB document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("cf3977abf592d19962ff7982"),
    "T1Column1" : "CLient",
    "T2.LoanTable" : [ 
        {
            "T2Column1" : "Name",
            "T2Column2" : "Saldo",
            "T3.Guarantor" : [ 
                {
                    "T3Column1" : "Name",
                    "T3Column2" : "Saldo"
                }, 
                {
                    "T3Column1" : "Name",
                    "T3Column2" : "Saldo"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "T2Column1" : "Name",
            "T2Column2" : "Saldo",
            "T3.Guarantor" : [ 
                {
                    "T3Column1" : "Name",
                    "T3Column2" : "Saldo"
                }, 
                {
                    "T3Column1" : "Name",
                    "T3Column2" : "Saldo"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Step 1** did to **ClientTable** in **MongoDBOutput**

[image: ClientTable]

**Step 2** did to **LoanTable**

[image: LoanTable]

I have problem with third level.

Comment: "I have problem with third level" means you already manged to do it for the other two levels? If so, please show us the relevant code and where you have the problems with the third level.

Answer (score 0):

[Third Level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbz7n.png)
  I need to populate the level with the hierarchical information